# Matlab same markers' color of line

Tags: matlab, graph, colors, matlab-figure

I defined 4 colors:

```
color_green = [31 135 16] ./ 255;
color_red = [244 56 47] ./ 255;
color_light_blue = [23 222 230] ./ 255;
color_purple = [192 4 247] ./ 255;
```

and because I have a lot of numbers, I'm using [this function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42560-line-fewer-markers) 
I'd like to use the same line color for the markers. I tried like this

```
line_fewer_markers(x,y1,30,'s','LineStyle', 'none', 'LineWidth', 2,'MarkerFaceColor','color_red');
plot(x,y2,'Color', color_red,'LineWidth',2);
```

but doesn't work. if I replace `color_red` with `'r'`, the entire square become red, while I need colored only the edge; and I need the exact red of `color_red` because I'll do this thing for other graphs.
If I use the standard color Matlab gives, it works. But I can't use that colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the *string* `'color_red'` rather than the *variable* `color_red` to `line_fewer_markers`.

```
line_fewer_markers(x,y1,30,'s', ...
                'LineStyle', 'none', ...
                'LineWidth', 2, ...
                'MarkerFaceColor', color_red);  %<---- Pass the VARIABLE not a string
```

Also, you're setting the [`MarkerFaceColor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html#property_markerfacecolor) which is the center portion of the marker. You want to set the `MarkerFaceColor` to `none` and instead set the [`MarkerEdgeColor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html#property_markeredgecolor).

```
line_fewer_markers(x,y1,30,'s', ...
                'LineStyle', 'none', ...
                'LineWidth', 2, ...
                'MarkerFaceColor', 'none', ...   %<-- Don't fill the markers
                'MarkerEdgeColor', color_red);   %<-- Set the EdgeColor
```

Comment: With `function red_color=...` says Function definitions are not permitted in this context.

Comment: @Shika93 Why are you writing `function red_color=` ?? That doesn't appear anywhere in my code. Also it's `color_red`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that I should to put `'MarkerEdgeColor', color_red` at the end of the code. Now works. Thanks!